# I cannot make the button in GridControl do the action

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

i have this code that add column and button to gridControl

```
private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();

    r[0] = cmbProject.Text;
    r[1] = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Le Nom").ToString();
    r[2] = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Quantité Restante");
    r[3] = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Longueur");

    dt.Rows.Add(r);

    deleteButton = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
   deleteButton.Buttons[0].Kind = ButtonPredefines.Delete;
    GridColumn column = gridView2.Columns["Projet"];
    column.ColumnEdit = deleteButton;
    column.ShowButtonMode = ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways;
    deleteButton.ButtonClick += btnDelete_Click;
}
```

and this is my code of button btnDelete

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView2.DeleteSelectedRows();
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XWGV.png)

all code working fine but i cannot make the deleteButton remove the selected row in gridview,Can anyone help me, i am using DevExpress WinForms GridControl.

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T462908/the-gridview-deleteselectedrows-method-removes-group-rows

Comment: thanks for your help,but my button is within gridview, i added screenshot ,thanks again.

Comment: Does btnDelete_Click event handler method fire when you click delete button in grid cell??

Comment: @Niranjan Kala This is where I'm stuck, in my head this code:deleteButton.ButtonClick += btnDelete_Click;
 do the job ,but in realty does not.

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah: Try to set 'OptionsBehavior -> Editable = True' of the column and then check whether event fire or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go through following references:
[DevExpress XtraGrid RepositoryItemButtonEdit event is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831600/devexpress-xtragrid-repositoryitembuttonedit-event-is-not-firing)

Please check whether you set the **this.gridView1.OptionsBehavior.Editable** property to false. So, in-place editors are not activated and, therefore, their events are not fired.

References:
[Repository Button Column Events Not Firing](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ30867/repository-button-column-events-not-firing)
[Repository ButtonEdit Click Event only fires on first click](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T403867/repository-buttonedit-click-event-only-fires-on-first-click)

Comment: thanks for your help ,i add this code gridView2.Columns["Projet"].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;after that i add this code deleteButton.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor